# Clothing modifier is pulling clothing up instead of down

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a character I am trying to clothe and I've done it by duplicating part of the character and modeling it after that, and by cloth sewing and with both I get the cloth sucking into the mesh or pulling itself upwards so far it doesn't cover the body anymore. The clothing mesh isn't parented to any rig or other mesh that I can think of.

here are the pictures of it in order from when it starts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and the cloth never comes back down it just floats in air.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us some of the intermediary frames so we can see what's happening? It looks like some part of it is having a collision problem that is causing the entire mesh to freak out. Sharing your file could help too.

Comment: It appears you haven't pinned the straps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that might be going on.  One is the collision size of the mesh collider:

[image]

Here my mesh collider's "outer" setting is so high that my cloth floats above it.  If that's too high, your cloth won't ever cling to your body.

The other thing is that your dress is too small.  It's about as wide as the cross section of the model, but just like a circle has to be pi times bigger than its diameter to wrap around, so does your cloth have to be about pi times bigger than your body to wrap around.  Your dress tries to minimize the size of the sewing lines, and to do that, it scrunches up at the waist, pulling the rest of the dress with it.